# Set ASP.net Session Timeout Based on IP Address

Tags: asp.net, session, ip-address, session-timeout

Is it possible to programmatically set the session timeout for a user-session based on the user's IP address?

Example: if IP address is in the range of 192.0.X then set session timeout to 6 hours. Otherwise, leave at default set in web.config (or set to 30 minutes).

Presumably this would be done in `Global.asax:Session_Start`. For now I would be ok with just using the IP address of the user's first request in a session (allowing for the fact that a user could change IP addresses mid-session).

ASP.net 3.5, IIS 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test for the IP range, you can use: `Request.UserHostAddress.StartsWith("192.0.")`.
Then set timeout using `Session.Timeout` property.

C# example:

```
if(Request.UserHostAddress.StartsWith("192.0."))
{
  Session.Timeout = 360; // 6 hours
}
```

Do this in Global: Session_Start event as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Yuo can set the Session.Timeout property for the session to something other than the default in code.

Answer (score 0):

you can change session timeout in web.config
write this code in system.web session state timeout=540/> //6 hours

Answer (score -1):

I think the Session.Timeout property sets the timeout for the whole application rather than the user session. I don't think you can have multiple timeouts within one application.

Options are to have two sites/applications one for the long-timeout users and another one for the others.

You could also use your own session management by creating a session provider or use a complete custom way to handle session state.

Another option is to add JavaScript to the pages of the long-timeout users to keep the session alive. Check this [article](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Keep-Session-Alive.aspx)

Comment: Wrong. `Session.Timeout` is set per session. If you set `Session.Timeout` in code, it will be set for the current session only.

Comment: good to know, the documentation usually talks about setting it in web.config and there it is application wide. But the fact that is is a property of the Session object should have told me that here it is for one specific session.